# No result for xhtml parsing using Beautiful Soup

Tags: xhtml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some xhtml from `http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/vga?format=rss` in my process of creating a search engine, using the Beautiful Soup module. But I get no results when I type this into my Python 2.7 shell:

```
 >>>soup.select('div.entry')
[]
```

Maybe I'm not parsing the xhtml correctly, but I don't understand why I'm getting an empty set.

Comment: I tried `(div.feedEntryContent)` and I got the same result. Did you inspect element on the page? When I did, I saw `<xhtml:div class="feedEntryContent" base="http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/vga?format=rss">`. How do I parse the xhtml in that case?

Comment: What xhtml? rss isn't xhtml.